# How to end a php functionality if their is no response in some time

Tags: php

I'm using neverbounce api in my project to check the email is valid or not. Usually neverbounce returning 5 result codes as a response [result codes](https://neverbounce.com/help/understanding-and-downloading-results/result-codes).In this, we'll get response for status code 0 to 3 in almost 3-4 seconds. but the last status code for **unknown emails** took almost 30 seconds to get the result. They are providing a timeout option in the API itself but it is not working. I contacted the support team but no use still the issue exists.
So I need to exit the functionality and return a default value if the response didn't receive from API. I tried by using **set_time_limit(5);** but it didn't work.Any help is appreciable.

This is the code that we're using

```
$res = 0;
try {
    // Make verification request, specify optional $max_execution_time
    $result = \NeverBounce\Single::check($email, // Email to verify
        true, // Address info
        true, // Credits info
        5// Timeout in seconds
    );
    if (!empty($result->result_integer)) {
        $res = $result->result_integer;
    } else {
        $res = 0;
    }
    // Call wrapper method here
} catch (\NeverBounce\Errors\AuthException $e) {
    // The API credentials used are bad, have you reset them recently?
    $res = 0;
} catch (\NeverBounce\Errors\BadReferrerException $e) {
    // The script is being used from an unauthorized source, you may need to
    // adjust your app's settings to allow it to be used from here
    $res = 0;
} catch (\NeverBounce\Errors\ThrottleException $e) {
    // Too many requests in a short amount of time, try again shortly or adjust
    // your rate limit settings for this application in the dashboard
    $res = 0;
} catch (\NeverBounce\Errors\HttpClientException $e) {
    // An error occurred processing the request, something may be wrong with
    // the Curl PHP extension or your network
    $res = 0;
} catch (\NeverBounce\Errors\GeneralException $e) {
    // A non recoverable API error occurred check the message for details
    $res = 0;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An error occurred unrelated to the API
    $res = 0;
}
return $res;
```

Comment: You could start your script as a background process, save the start time and in regular intervals check if the process is still running. If it is, just kill it.

Comment: Seems like you discovered a bug in their PHP api wrapper. When looking into the `Single::check` method, one can see that the timeout parameter is given to the `request` method in the params array. But in the `request` method, the timeout option is then retrieved by `$this->timeout`. Therefore the timeout parameter is never used. Your best bet is probably to open an issue in their Github repository and wait for them to fix the problem: https://github.com/NeverBounce/NeverBounceAPI-PHP